# How do I compare two objects to see if they are the same instance, in Dart?

Tags: dart

Say I have a class that has many instance variables,. I want to overload the == operator (and hashCode) so I can use instances as keys in maps.

```
class Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  SomeClass c;
  SomeOtherClass d;
  // etc.

  bool operator==(Foo other) {
    // Long calculation involving a, b, c, d etc.
  }
}
```

The comparison calculation may be expensive, so I want to check  if `other` is the same instance as `this` before making that calculation.

How do I invoke the == operator provided by the Object class to do this ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're looking for "[identical](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/identical.html)", which will check if 2 instances are the same.

```
identical(this, other);
```

A more detailed example?

```dart
class Person {
  String ssn;
  String name;

  Person(this.ssn, this.name);

  // Define that two persons are equal if their SSNs are equal
  bool operator ==(Person other) {
    return (other.ssn == ssn);
  }
}

main() {
  var bob = new Person('111', 'Bob');
  var robert = new Person('111', 'Robert');

  print(bob == robert); // true

  print(identical(bob, robert)); // false, because these are two different instances
}
```

Comment: if you override `operator ==` you will also need to override `hashCode`. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22999113/9449426) for how to do this

Comment: What if i want to check If a list of model already contains a particular object ?

Comment: @NearlHuscarl pointed to a great thread, but the specific answer is already outdated. See the one regarding `object.hash()` for Dart 2.14 and up

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`identical(this, other)`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/identical.html).

Answer (score 3):

*For completeness, this is a supplemental answer to the existing answers.*

If some class `Foo` does *not* override `==`, then the default implementation is to return whether they are the same object. The [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) states:

> The default behavior for all Objects is to return true if and only if this object and other are the same object.

Answer (score 3):

That's my way how I compare deep 2 Objects they're not the same:

```
class Foo{
 String uid;
 bool isActiv;
 Foo(this.uid, this.isActiv){}
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FooToJson(this);
}

Foo A = Foo("alpha", true);
Foo B = Foo("alpha", true);

print(A.toJson().toString() == B.toJson().toString()); // true
B.uid = "beta";
print(A.toJson().toString() == B.toJson().toString()); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) library

```
class Foo extends EquatableMixin{
   int? a;
   int? b;
   SomeClass? c;
   SomeOtherClass? d;
   Foo(this.a,this.b,this.c,this.d);
         
   // this does the job, it overrides the hashcode and equals operator
   // give all properties to this `props`
   @override
   List<Object> get props => [a,b,c,d];
}
        
        
    
class SomeOtherClass with EquatableMixin{
  String name;
          
  SomeOtherClass(this.name);
          
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];
}

   
class SomeClass with EquatableMixin{
  String name;
      
  SomeClass(this.name);
      
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];
      
}
    


Foo foo = 
   Foo(1,2,SomeOtherClass("roger"),SomeOtherClassObject("mack"));

Foo foo2 = 
   Foo(1,2,SomeOtherClass("roger"),SomeOtherClassObject("mack"));
            
print(foo == foo2) // prints true
```

So, we don't need to manually override `==` and `hashcode()` methods
the library will do that.

*Note : the inner objects (SomeClass and SomeOtherClass) should also use EquatableMixin, we can extends this or use as a mixin too*

Comment: A lot of boilerplate..

Comment: do you have any better solution ? @c-an

Comment: I like this solution, because it has minimal boilerplate, and makes your code readable and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to compare two pass-by-reference Objects like class, List, Map, Set or etc...
you will need to set variables as const variables to be able to compare them because the compiler compares them by **address or hashCode** like the below code.

```
   class Foo {
      final int a;
      final int b;
      final SomeClass c;
      const Foo({required this.a, required this.b, required this.c});
    }
    
    class SomeClass {
      final List values;
      const SomeClass(this.values);
    }
    void main() {
      const foo1 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
      const foo2 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
      final foo3 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
      final foo4 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
      print(foo1 == foo2); // true
      print(foo3 == foo4); //false
      print(foo1.hashCode == foo2.hashCode); // true
      print(foo3.hashCode == foo4.hashCode); // false
    }
```

But we have a big problem we can assign a constant to variables defined at compile time and we can't do this at runtime, see below solutions :)

### solution 1:

will need to override hashCode and == methods like the below code.

```
void main() {
  const foo1 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  const foo2 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  final foo3 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  final foo4 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  print(foo1 == foo2); // true
  print(foo3 == foo4); //true
  print(foo1.hashCode == foo2.hashCode); // true
  print(foo3.hashCode == foo4.hashCode); // true
}

class Foo {
  final int a;
  final int b;
  final SomeClass c;
  const Foo({required this.a, required this.b, required this.c});
  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(a.hashCode, b.hashCode, c.hashCode);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return identical(this, other) ||
        other is Foo &&
            runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
            hashCode == other.hashCode;
  }
}

class SomeClass {
  final List values;
  const SomeClass(this.values);
  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hashAll(values);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return identical(this, other) ||
        other is Foo &&
            runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
            hashCode == other.hashCode;
  }
}
```

### solution 2 *(the best solution)*:

use [Equtable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package

```
void main() {
  const foo1 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  const foo2 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  final foo3 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  final foo4 = Foo(a: 1, b: 1, c: SomeClass([]));
  print(foo1 == foo2); // true
  print(foo3 == foo4); //true
  print(foo1.hashCode == foo2.hashCode); // true
  print(foo3.hashCode == foo4.hashCode); // true
}

class Foo extends Equatable {
  final int a;
  final int b;
  final SomeClass c;
  const Foo({required this.a, required this.b, required this.c});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [a, b, c];
}

class SomeClass extends Equatable {
  final List values;
  const SomeClass(this.values);

  @override
List<Object?> get props => [values];
}
```

### the sources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCKaFaU4jdk

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html

Answer (score 1):

On a different yet similar note, in cases where the framework calls to check the equality among the objects e.g. in case of `list.toSet()` to get the unique elements from a list, `identical(this, other)` may not be a choice. That time the class must override the `== operator` and the `hasCode()` methods.

However for this case another way could be to use the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package. This saves a lot of boiler plate code and is especially handy when you have lot of model classes.