# What's a good recipe for overriding hashcode in Dart?

Tags: dart, hashcode

I find myself wanting to override hashcode and == for an object, and I'm wondering if there are best practices for how to implement a hashcode that depends on multiple attributes, and it seems like there are some Dart-specific considerations.

The simplest answer would be to XOR the hashes of all the attributes together, and it's probably not too bad. There's also an example in Dart Up and Running at https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html

```dart
  // Override hashCode using strategy from Effective Java, Chapter 11.
 int get hashCode {
   int result = 17;
   result = 37 * result + firstName.hashCode;
   result = 37 * result + lastName.hashCode;
   return result;
 }
```

but that seems like it expects truncating integer semantics and in Dart overflowing the range of JS integers seems bad for hashing.

We could also do that and just truncate to 32 bits after each operation.

For my application the expected size of the set is very small and almost anything would do, but I'm surprised not to see a standard recipe for the general case. Does anyone have any experience or strong experience with this?

Comment: Almost -1 from me for saying "recipe", but since the quality of your question is good, no -1 from me. Surely the term you should be using in your title, is Algorithm, or even "way"(as in, a good way, or a good algorithm) rather than "a good recipe". I can understand if you think the term algorithm sounds like showing off. You could say 'way', but using the term "recipe" is below lame

Comment: Perhaps look for examples from another language with arbitrary precision integers. Smalltalk has these I believe.

Comment: Dart's integers are funny in that they're arbitrary on the VM, but if you're compiling to JavaScript you get Javascript's limits. So you'd want to truncate, and the interesting question is where and how to do that best. It's presumably some combination of shift/multiply, XOR and truncate. That's also what Smalltalk tends to do. The devil is in the details.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The [**quiver** package](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) provides helper functions `hash2`, `hash3`, etc., which simplify the task of implementing `hashCode`, with some assurance that it works properly under the Dart VM *and* when compiled to JavaScript.

```dart
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';

class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  @override
  bool operator ==(o) => o is Person && name == o.name && age == o.age;

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(name.hashCode, age.hashCode);
}
```

Also see [this post](http://pchalin.blogspot.com/2014/04/defining-equality-and-hashcode-for-dart.html) for a slightly lengthier discussion.

Comment: Remember to add quiver as a dependency. In your pubspec.yaml: `quiver: '>=0.18.0<0.19.0'`.

Comment: wouldn't `hash2(name, age)` be sufficient?

Comment: add `import 'package:quiver/core.dart';` for `hash2()`

Comment: Since Dart 2.14, you can use `Object.hash()`: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys. See manikanta's answer.

Answer (score 86):

Since version 2.14, Dart language added support for [`Object.hash()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-core/Object/hash.html), along with [`Object.hashAll()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-core/Object/hashAll.html) and [`Object.hashAllUnordered()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-core/Object/hashAllUnordered.html)

`hash()` doc:

> Creates a combined hash code for a number of objects.

Example:

```dart
class SomeObject {
  final Object a, b, c;
  SomeObject(this.a, this.b, this.c);

  bool operator==(Object other) =>
      other is SomeObject && a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c;

  int get hashCode => Object.hash(a, b, c); // <----- here
}
```

Note from doc on implementation:

> The hash value generated by this function is not guranteed to be stable over different runs of the same program, or between code run in different isolates of the same program. The exact algorithm used may differ between different platforms, or between different versions of the platform libraries, and it may depend on values that change on each program execution.

Comment: This should be upvoted. It is the recommended method: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys

Comment: What if the class has a parent? Can I do `Object.hash(a, b, c, super)`?

Comment: @nuynait No, you can't use `super` on its own as a valid expression. I think the best option is: `Object.hash(super.hashCode, a, b, c)`.

Comment: To clarify, `Object.hashAll()` should be used for Lists? And to combine that hash with non-Lists, it would be `Object.hash(a, Object.hashAll(list), c)`? How to make `hashAll` work on a List of Lists?

Answer (score 44):

In the interests of minimizing dependencies, if you are already depending on flutter, but not depending on something like `quiver`, the  `dart:ui` library contains utilites, `hashValues` and `hashList` for creating and combining hash values. If combining list values, one must be careful to ensure the equality operator and hashcode match behaviour. If the hash code computes it's hash deeply, then use deep equality, else, use shallow equality.

```
class Example {
    final String value1;
    final Object value2;
    final List<Object> deep;
    final List<Object> shallow;

    Example({this.value1, this.value2, this.deep, this.shallow});

    @override
    operator ==(o) =>
        o is Example &&
        o.value1 == value1 &&
        o.value2 == value2 &&
        listEquals(o.deep, deep) &&
        o.shallow == shallow;

    @override
    int get hashCode => hashValues(value1, value2, hashList(deep), shallow);
}
```

[Flutter API docs for hashValues](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/hashValues.html)

[Flutter API docs for hashList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/hashList.html)

Comment: Awesome, minimizing dependencies is always in my interest!

Comment: Really your answer saved me thank you so much

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `hashValues` will return a different hash for two different arguments? Or does it a good job minimizing this risk drastically?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `hashValues` will return a different has for two different arguments, no hash function can make this guarantee because the key space is generally smaller than value space of the object. But as far as I understand, the function seeks to minimize the chances of a collision, while minimizing computational complexity.

Comment: Note that now both hashValues and hashList are deprecated. Use Object.hashAll() and Object.hashAllUnordered() instead: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/hashList.html

Answer (score 19):

The [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package can help

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name, age];
}
```

Now Person will use `==` and `hashCode` from Equatable, which takes `props` list that you give

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with models with extends from ChangeNotifier when you use provider StateManagement

Comment: @NiklasLehnfeld if you need to extend another class, you can use mixin. E.g. `class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier with EquatableMixin`

Comment: This works only with immutable objects so all member variables must be final. Not so useful if your class objects change over time.

Comment: @NiklasLehnfeld you shoudn't extend models from ChangeNotifier. You're doing something wrong. Models should be immutable. If you want reactive fields, consider MobX or Get.

Answer (score 12):

I recomend "equatable" plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Example:

Raw mode:

```
class Person {
  final String name;

  const Person(this.name);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is Person &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

With equatable :

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  final String name;

  Person(this.name);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Since Dart is so similar to Java, you can surely find good references on hashCodes for Java that are applicable for Dart too.

A little googling took me to the [Wikipedia page on Java's `Object.hashCode()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29). Has a very basic example for the hashcode of a simple object. A popular methodology is to perform a multiplication with a prime number (different ones) and adding some value for each property of the object.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier) f.e. explains why the number 31 is chosen for multiplication for the `String.hashCode()` method.

More detailed examples of hashcode implementations can be easily found using Google.

Comment: I don't know that Dart is so similar to Java. In particular, it differs in its handling of integer types, and the common hash for Java would, if applied to a large number of things, overflow out of Javascript integer range, which would be bad.

Comment: Well, Java ints overflow as well. You may want to use int32 or int64 from the dart:typed_data package so that your hashcodes are consistent.

Comment: Java ints overflow by wrapping around. Javascript ints (and Dart ints when compiled to Javascript) overflow by turning into doubles, which is much worse for hashing. Using an int32 datatype would help, but dart:typed_data doesn't have a single int type, it only has collections.