# Dart/Flutter : How to compare if 2 objects are equivalent without using Equatable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to test if 2 objects, 2 different instances of the same class, have all the same property values;
(ie. see if they are logically equivalent).

I don't want to just check for if they are the exact same object (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428735/how-do-i-compare-two-objects-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-instance-in-dart)).

**And** I don't wish to use the [Equatable package](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-equatable-package-simplify-equality-comparisons-1a96a3fc4864), simply because I don't want to mark my properties as `final`.

What I want is essentially a simple deep comparison of all properties of 2 objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to override two methods in your class to perform a custom comparison.

1. the `==` operator
2. the `hashCode` getter

For example:

```
class MyObj {
  String name;
  
  MyObj(this.name);
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (o is MyObj && o.runtimeType == runtimeType) {
      if (o.name == name) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

Testing this:

```
void main() {
  MyObj objA = MyObj('billy');
  MyObj objB = MyObj('bob');
  MyObj objC = MyObj('billy');
  
  print('object A == object B? ${objA == objB}');
  print('object A == object C? ${objA == objC}');
 
}
```

Should produce:

```
object A == object B? false
object A == object C? true
```

For overriding `hashCode` for multiple properties, perhaps check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20577606/2301224).

Comment: I was hoping for an easier way - but searching has not found one.  And this certainly works.  I'll add to the answer that for any `Map` or `List` properties, `DeepCollectionEquality().equals(o, this)` can be used (need to `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`).