# if test statement is false even if the two data are equal

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to do a filter function for a Listview.

Here is the code of the filter function :

```
   void filterSearchResults() {
    List<Club> dummySearchList = List<Club>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(widget.club);
    if(currentEnvironment != '' ) {
      List<Club> dummyListData = List<Club>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((club) {
        if(club.environment == currentEnvironment) {
          dummyListData.add(club);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        clubs.clear();
        clubs.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        clubs.clear();
        clubs.addAll(widget.club);
      });
    }
  }
```

It's suposed to go through every Club I got, and if the environment of the Club is equal with the value of `currentEnvironment`, the club is added to a list for printing them out.

But the `if(club.environment == currentEnvironment)` always send me false.  if I check both of my values, I found that the string of the current club object is "Mountain" and the `currentEnvironment` is "Mountain" too. They both supposed to be of the String type.

With `if(club.environment == "Mountain")` it's working as presumed.

I get my clubs with local Json, and the `currentEnvironment` is stored in SharedPreferences

Code to get my `currentEnvironment` :

```
class ClubList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Club> club;
  ClubList({Key key, this.club}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ClubListState createState() => _ClubListState();
}

class _ClubListState extends State<ClubList> {

  var clubs = List<Club>();
  String currentEnvironment;

  @override
  setData() {
    getSelectedEnvironment().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        currentEnvironment = value;
        print("currentEnvironment ${currentEnvironment}");
        filterSearchResults();
      });
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    clubs.addAll(widget.club);
    setData();
    filterSearchResults();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> getSelectedEnvironment() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return prefs.getString("selectedEnvironment");
  }
```

I don't know if you need other information, tell me if it's the case.

I found the solution to my problem. I just have to call the `filterSearchResults()` in my `setData()`. Like that, the function wait to have a value to be launched.

Comment: have you try with this other way ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428735/how-do-i-compare-two-objects-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-instance-in-dart

Comment: try to remove ```@override``` from ```setData()``` so your code compiles correctly.

Comment: What happens if you change the if statement to this: `if(club.environment.compareTo(currentEnvironment) == 0) `

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that both `String` instances have the same content?  That is, with the way you print the strings, it would be very hard to tell if one of them has trailing whitespace.  It also is conceivable that one has homoglyphs and only *looks* like "Mountain".

Comment: @Jamesdlin I just checked the if statement in the `filterSearchResults` function with @AmitPrajapati solution. The result is false and by checking the value of `currentEnvironment`, it's null. I'm working on it now. thanks for both of your advices

Comment: @aligator I edited my question with the future call that i make. And removing `@override` seems to do nothing.

Comment: check if their lengths are equal

Comment: I found a solution and edited my post. Thanks everyone. i wont forget the `identical(this, other)` function for dart !