# Are int, double, String constants and canonicalized by default in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    void main(){
    int a=3;
    int b=3;
    print(identical(a,b));
```

> returns true

```
    double c=3.2;
    double d=3.2;
    print(identical(c,d));
```

> returns true, same for String type

```
    List l1=[1,2,3];
    List l2=[1,2,3];
    print(identical(l1,l2));
    }
```

> But for list returns false.How?.As int,double,string override ==operator does that have anything to do with identical returning true for these types.

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428735/how-do-i-compare-two-objects-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-instance-in-dart

Comment: Still didn't get bro, so here my objects that I am comparing are same instances?

Comment: `bool`, `int`, `double`, and `String` are all *immutable*, so Dart can canonicalize their literals as an optimization without affecting behavior (other than `identical` itself).  The same cannot be said for `List`, `Map`, or `Set` literals since they are mutable.  Two separate `[1, 2, 3]` literals cannot be canonicalized since mutating one should not affect the other.

Comment: Okay thank you for answering

Comment: @jamesdlin well described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the false because a list is an indexable collection of objects with a length. In identical checks, two instances are the same or not but you can convert this instance into a string.

```
  List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  List l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  print(identical(l1.toString(), l2.toString())); //true
```

For list comparison, you can use `listEquals`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
void main() {
  List<int> l1 = [1, 2, 3,4];
  List<int> l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  print(listEquals(l1, l2)); //true
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks and what about title of my question,what I said is true?

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Ok, is there some more information about what u said about lists behaving different

Comment: for more please link target part https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/identical.html and link target https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Link/create.html

Comment: Ok thank you, Got it

Comment: you are welcome, have a great ride with flutter.