# how to explain the output of this Dart code - List of List<int>

Tags: dart

Does anyone agree that the output of this code is surprising?

If so, can anyone explain what is happening.  Why does `add(499)` result in three new elements with value `499` instead of just one?

`shared[0]` has type `List<int>` so add performed on `shared[0]` should have no effect on `shared[1]`.

```
// output is
[[], [], []]
[[499, 599], [499, 599], [499, 599]]
499
599
499
599
499
599
```

Dart program:

```dart
main()
{
  var xx = <int>[];
  final shared = List.filled(3, xx);
  print(shared);
  shared[0].add(499);
  shared[1].add(599);
  print(shared);
  for (int k = 0; k < shared.length; ++k) {
    for (int j = 0; j < shared[k].length; ++j)
      print(shared[k][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `shared[1]` is the same object as `shared[0]`, which is the same as `xx`. [Dart uses the same pass-reference-by-value semantics for passing objects like Java and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170094/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-pass-by-reference-in-modern-languages-like-dart).

Comment: From the API documentation for [`List.filled`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.filled.html): "All elements of the created list share the same `fill` value.... You can use `List.generate` to create a list with a fixed length and a new object at each position."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `shared[0]` has type `List<int>` so add performed on `shared[0]` should have no effect on `shared[1]`.

The fact that `shared[0]` is `List<int>` is orthogonal to the fact that `shared[0]` and `shared[1]` are both **object references** to the same *single* `List<int>` that you created on line 1: `var xx = <int>[];`.

---

Let's go line-by-line:

1. `var xx = <int>[];`

   - This creates a new empty, resizable `List<int>` object in the program.

     - I'm not a Dart user, but from what I can tell this object will live on Dart's GC heap, just like `new List<int>()` in C# or `new ArrayList<Integer>()` in Java - and objects that live on the GC heap can have any number of inbound references from elsewhere in the program.
2. `final shared = List.filled(3, xx);`

   - [This creates](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) a second new `List<List<int>>` object, with an initial size of `3`, and each of those 3 elements is a reference to the `xx` object passed into `filled`.
   - [The `final` modifier](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) just means that the `shared` variable (an object reference) cannot be re-assigned. It does not mean that `shared` is an immutable object or in any way read-only, nor does it confer copy-semantics or value-semantics on object-references.
3. `print(shared);`

   - This prints "`[[], [], []]`" because at-this-point, the `xx` list is still empty.
4. `shared[0].add(499);`

   - At this point, the `xx` list is still empty, so calling `.add(499)` will add the first value to `xx`.
   - And this will be instantly visible in `shared[1]`, `shared[2]`, and `xx` if you were to look with your debugger.
   - Another way to demonstrate that all those [object-references point to the same object is by using `identical()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428735/how-do-i-compare-two-objects-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-instance-in-dart).
5. `shared[1].add(599);`

   - Again, this is the same as doing `shared[2].add(599)` or `xx.add(599)`.
6. `print(shared);`

   - This prints "`[[499, 599], [499, 599], [499, 599]]`".
   - Perhaps instead, think of the print output as "`[xx, xx, xx]`".
7. `for (int k = 0; k < shared.length; ++k) for (int j = 0; j < shared[k].length; ++j) print(shared[k][j]);`

   - This does effectively the same thing as `print(shared)`, except rendering each nested element on its own line, thus hiding the the nested structure of the list.
   - If you change the `print` call-site to something like this: `print( "k: $k, j: $j == ${shared[k][j]}");` then you get output that's easier to understand:

     ```
     k: 0, j: 0 == 499
     k: 0, j: 1 == 599
     k: 1, j: 0 == 499
     k: 1, j: 1 == 599
     k: 2, j: 0 == 499
     k: 2, j: 1 == 599
     ```

---

See for yourself by copying+pasting the code below to Dartpad.dev:

```dart
main()
{
  var xx = <int>[];
  final shared = List.filled(3, xx);
  print(shared);
  shared[0].add(499);
  shared[1].add(599);
  print(shared);
  
  print("");
  for (int k = 0; k < shared.length; ++k) {
    for (int j = 0; j < shared[k].length; ++j) {
      print( "k: $k, j: $j == ${shared[k][j]}");
    }
  }

  print("");
  
  var areReferencesToSameObject_xx_0 = identical(xx, shared[0]);
  var areReferencesToSameObject_xx_1 = identical(xx, shared[1]);
  var areReferencesToSameObject_xx_2 = identical(xx, shared[2]);
  var areReferencesToSameObject_1_2  = identical(shared[1], shared[2]);
  var areReferencesToSameObject_xx_shared = identical(xx, shared);
  
  print("xx and shared[0] are the same object: $areReferencesToSameObject_xx_0"); // true
  print("xx and shared[1] are the same object: $areReferencesToSameObject_xx_1"); // true
  print("xx and shared[2] are the same object: $areReferencesToSameObject_xx_2"); // true
  print("shared[1] and shared[2] are the same object: $areReferencesToSameObject_1_2"); // true
  print("shared and xx are the same object: $areReferencesToSameObject_xx_shared"); // false
}
```

Gives me this output:

```
[[], [], []]
[[499, 599], [499, 599], [499, 599]]

k: 0, j: 0 == 499
k: 0, j: 1 == 599
k: 1, j: 0 == 499
k: 1, j: 1 == 599
k: 2, j: 0 == 499
k: 2, j: 1 == 599

xx and shared[0] are the same object: true
xx and shared[1] are the same object: true
xx and shared[2] are the same object: true
shared[1] and shared[2] are the same object: true
shared and xx are the same object: false
```